# UWP - DriveInfo gives access denied for removable storage even if included in capability

Tags: c#, uwp, driveinfo

I work on an UWP application who manage removable devices.  So, I made sure to have this in the manifest.

```
<Capabilities>
   <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage"/>
</Capabilities>
```

I need to obtain the free and total space of the device.  So, I use DriveInfo like this.

```
DriveInfo z = new DriveInfo(@"E:\");
long x = z.TotalFreeSpace;
```

This gives the following exception when he tries to obtain the free space and assign it to x :

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException : 'Access to the path 'E:\' is denied.'
```

As you can see, the drive is really a removable drive.

[image]

The process I need should occur once the drive as been detected and added.  So, this happens in the Added event of a `DeviceWatcher`. I see the device is not ready `IsReady=false` in the watch window.  Maybe I try to access it too soon?  The event is "Added", not "Adding" and the `UnauthorizedAccessException` is not the one who should occur.  I suppose a `DeviceNotReadyException` would be more appropriate. So, I conclude the problem is not linked to the fact it is not ready.

Comment: Check out https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/UWP-External-file-system-access-and-environment-variables/ this may help resolve your issues

Comment: Yes, I have seen the broad filesystem access capability, but I will need to justify this choice to Microsoft, something I would not be able to do.  So, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Even with the `removableStorage` capability declared, you still need to use the UWP APIs to access the files - this means using `StorageFolder` APIs. You can use:

```
var drives = await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
```

To retrieve all removable drives that you can query. The `KnownFolders.RemovableDevices` is actually a virtual folder which contains a subfolder for each removable drive (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders.removabledevices?view=winrt-19041)). To check the drive letter, you can check the `Path` of each of the folders.

To retrieve the remaining free space, you can check the properties of the removable storage folder:

```
var properties = await folder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(
    new string[] { "System.FreeSpace" });
return (UInt64)properties["System.FreeSpace"];
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, but the GetFolders is irrelevant as I want to be notified by the watcher.  Concerning the properties, they are so confusing to find which are supported by which device.  I found out DriveInfo and wanted to use it.  I used your method as a workaround and notified the framework team on github.  As your solution is near what I did, you are the winner of a point!